# Any difference between inverted microscope objective vs normal microscope objective?

Tags: microscopy

I'm planning to build an inverted microscope and I am not sure if I can use a plane achromatic objective of a normal microscope for the inverted microscope as well. Are there any specific needs for the objective of an inverted microscope?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the way it works and certain structural differences ([reference](https://www.ntuh.gov.tw/LARD/DocLib1/%E5%80%92%E7%AB%8B%E9%A1%AF%E5%BE%AE%E9%8F%A1%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E7%94%B3%E8%AB%8B%E8%A1%A8%E6%A0%BC/Microscopy.pdf)), the decision of which kind of lens you need to use is left to your own personal choice based on your needs. You can find a list of the different lenses being offered by Olympus in [this link](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDAQFjAB&url=http://www.olympusamerica.com/files/seg_bio/Basics_of_Inv-Microscope.pdf&ei=YMOOU-XWJ4rDkgXizIGYBg&usg=AFQjCNHe05X36DyQXX3dsK0drWK56nUhwg&sig2=k6jGGbw7fDu_LGQBtTzKzg).